# How to get the values from the Vue 2 Editor?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get the data from the editor (vue 2 editor), I mean when the user chooses from the toolbar, for example, the link or image, I need to separate the values to save it separately on the database.

[image: This is the editor that I use]

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: I found this, https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor, custom image handler, I need when the user uploads an image need it to save on attachment table as a URL not Base64

Comment: Alright, good start. What did you tried with it?

Comment: when I upload it does not save anything

Comment: when I try to console log the form data it's looking empty, so I need just how to get the image path to save it on my database